# How can I make all folders in Finder "snap to grid"?

Tags: macos, finder

I don't like that files can be placed *anywhere*, even overlapping other files, in Finder. The files also don't reorganize to fit when resizing the window.

[image]

I do realize I can right click and select "Clean up", but I don't want to do that every time I drag and drop a file.

I found this setting to make everything "snap to grid" so it will stay organized in the Show View Options window. However, it only works for that specific folder. Is there any way to make it apply across everything in Finder? I tried clicking "Use as Defaults" but it appears to only apply to new folders.

[image]

Comment: The key may be as simple as Relaunching Finder.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The following steps applied "Snap to Grid" even for **previously created folders**.

**Tested on:**

- 10.6.x
- 10.7.3
- 10.8.x
- 10.9.x
- 10.12.5
- 10.15.7
- 12.x

1. Go to any folder control
2. Control click on the empty space
3. Click on Show View Options
4. In the "Sort by" drop down bar select "**Snap to Grid**"
5. **At the bottom of the window click on the "Use as Defaults"
   button**

**NOTE:** Because this will become the **default setup for ALL Finder windows** you may consider manipulating the Icon size, Grid spacing, Text size, Label position, Background, etc... accordingly.

**ALSO:** If folders do not appear to have snapped to grid on a previously created folder, **Relaunch Finder** or you could try to **toggle** the "Icon size" down and back up too refresh the current window.

This is where it is on 10.15 Catalina:
[image]

Comment: @Nathan Did you have any luck after trying the answer above, or is it still not functioning?

Comment: It worked, thanks! Sorry, I just forgot to come back and click the accept button :)

Comment: @Nathan No problem I am just glad it worked for you. :–)

Comment: works in 10.8 and 10.9 to, tested

Comment: works in 10.10 as well.

Comment: 10.10.2, "Snap To Grid" is in "Sort By" dropdown instead of "Arrange By"

Comment: Works on 10.11, too.

Comment: On `10.11.4` you don't need to click the **Use as Defaults** option.

Comment: I needed at least 1 file / directory in my folder in order to have the `snap to grid` option enabled. I still don't get what this is not the default option on MAC OS. It just creates a mess anyway. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: of course Apple, "the pinnacle of UI/UX", decided that by default it's better having a mess of files scattered in a folder, rather than neatly ordered in a grid :/

Comment: Works on 10.13 High Sierra, Thank you so much, I was thinking to move to windows due to this <3 However, is there any way to make it apply to "create new folder"?

Comment: I don't have the "Snap to grid" in the list, only the list of attributes you can sort by (MacOS 12.3.1)

Answer (score 15):

**Update for 10.10:** When you are in the "Show View Options" Menu, the **"Snap to Grid"** setting has been moved to the "Sort By:" drop down bar.

Answer (score -4):

Just highlight all the folders you want to clean up, and press clean up selection. It's that easy.

Comment: OP has already said *"I do realize I can right click and select "Clean up", but I don't like having to do that every time I drag and drop a folder/file."*

Comment: He already said he doesn't want to do this